# Timing issue with is_amp_endpoint()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to do disable an speed optimization plugin when the page/post is AMP. Its developer suggested to use `is_amp_endpoint()` to detect if AMP is running but I can't find the right place/time where to use it.

If I check it too early using `if (function_exists('is_amp_endpoint') && is_amp_endpoint())`, it gives a 500 error. If I check it within the AMP plugin code, it works but the optimization plugin has already run so it's too late.

How can I figure out where to run this check so that it happens after `is_amp_endpoint()` works but before the optimization execution?

Comment: It really depends on what that plugin is. You need to ask the plugin developer.

Comment: Wordpress core functions often throw 500 errors if they are called too early. If you turn on debug mode in your wp-config.php (`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, then you should be able to see what the specific error is. A little googling on the Wordpress developer docs will usually turn up which action it is safe to call the underlying function on, so you then call it from the earliest possible action. Plugins usually also register against the same actions, so another good option would be to check what the priority level of the plugin action is, and then register one level later than that.

Comment: In general, most actions of the core are not ready until after the `init` hook fires. The individual plugin may have its own bindings later than that which also may need to be satisfied. You can either go over the documentation for [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and work your way backwards until you find one that works, or examine the source code of the plugin manually to figure this out. Asking the developer directly may save you some time also.

Comment: @mopsyd - WP Debug is on, but strangely that error isn't logged. Others are...

Comment: That happens sometimes. To rule out the possibility of a fatal white screen error, you can use `register_shutdown_function(function(){ $error = error_get_last(); if ( !is_null($error) ){ var_dump($error);} } );`

Comment: Usually when that happens it's a compiletime error, which doesn't usually show up.

Comment: The above function will show you fatal errors though, even if they would normally whitescreen.

Comment: That function is giving some useful info I'm sharing with the plugin developer. Thank you.